# how to listen to markers/cue points on videos

Tags: marker, points, flv, cue-points

I would like to ask if it is possible for visual studio (c#), to listen to markers/cue points embedded into video files (flv or Mpeg4)?

Currently, I'm playing flv video using the QuartzTypeLib dll. I am able to play the video successfully. Is it possible for c# to observe a marker on the video so that I can trigger an event if that marker is reached?

Thank you very much.